# issue Reading DT (date and time) from opc ua siemens server C#

Tags: opc-ua, siemens

I'm trying to read the date and time (#DT) from Opc ua Server (Siemens) using opc ua DLLs of unifiedautomation. But i get wrong value:

siemens S7 1500                           opc ua client 
DT#2008-10-25-08:12:34.567      -->      17.09.1142 05:08:27

I'm using the following code:

```
var td = ReadValue(NodeId).ToByteArray();
long temp = BitConverter.ToInt64(td, 0);
DateTime dateTimeVar = new DateTime(temp);
```

ReadValue function:

```
public Variant ReadValue(string VariableIdentifier)
{
            Variant data = new Variant();

            List<DataValue> results = read(VariableIdentifier);
            if (results.Count > 0)
            {
                if (StatusCode.IsGood(results[0].StatusCode))
                {
                    data = results[0].WrappedValue;
                    m_OpcError = "OK";
                }
                else
                {
                    m_OpcError = results[0].StatusCode.Message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                m_OpcError = "ReadValue function: it Couldn't read data from OPC UA Server (empty data)";
            }

            return data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just came across the same problem. You need the split the result in a byte array beforehand.

```
var bytes = new byte[] { 32, 6, 37, 20, 25, 4, 135, 37 };//Test 25.06.2020 14:19:04
//Remove BCD
List<int> vals = new List<int>();
foreach (var bcd in bytes)
{
    int high = bcd >> 4;
    int low = bcd & 0xF;
    int number = 10 * high + low;
    vals.Add(number);
}
//Create Datetime
DateTime dt = new DateTime(vals[0] + 2000, vals[1], vals[2], vals[3], vals[4], vals[5]);
```