# Byte Array in string format back to datetime

Tags: c#, arrays, parsing, reverse-engineering, data-conversion

I need to interact with a service which is returning me a string.... however this is a representation of a Byte Array in text.

Then I need convert this string to a byte array and after convert it to DateTime....

To make things worse, I really do not know what type of encoding is been used.....the only few things I know are 2 samples that were provided to me:

- Exact received string: "32,6,23,8,69,80,48,36"       needs to give me the datetime: 17.6.2020 08:45:50
- Exact received string: "32,6,23,8,69,87,118,148"     needs to give me the datetime: 17.6.2020 17:45:57

Any idea on how to do this, or at least some points that could help me move on into a solution? Thanks.

**#Update1:**

I have tried the following code but the results are not what I am looking for:

```
byte[] bytes = { 32, 6, 23, 8, 69, 80, 48, 36 };
long longVar = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 0);
DateTime dateTimeVar = new DateTime(longVar);  // Result: 5/21/8264 9:36:06 AM

string t1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes); //  " \u0006\u0017\bEP0$"
string t2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes); // " \u0006\u0017\bEP0$"
string t3 = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(bytes); // " ᜈ䕐〤"
string t4 = Encoding.UTF32.GetString(bytes); // "��"
string t5 = Encoding.UTF7.GetString(bytes); // " \u0006\u0017\bEP0$"
string t6 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);  // IAYXCEVQMCQ=

long longVar = BitConverter.ToInt64({ 32, 6, 23, 8, 69, 87, 118, 148 }, 0); 
// This one even gives me a negative number: -7748910154844273120
```

**#Update2:**

I know that the dates are obtained from an OPC server and other systems in between....  what is happening till the data arrives in my service I really have no idea.... Meanwhile I google for OPC and datetime and got the following [link](https://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdkhp/1.0.0/html/_doc__opc_ua__base_model__data_types.html) about datetimes, maybe I get some clarification.

Comment: is this EXACTLY what is being given to you `32,6,23,8,69,80,48,36`

Comment: @TheGeneral I know how to do byte[] bytes = { 32, 6, 23, 8, 69, 80, 48, 36 }; this is not the problem... What I want to know is how to bring it back to DateTime

Comment: Can you share the exact string you are getting from the service ?

Comment: Are you asking us to guess the format?

Comment: @Dryadwoods - What do the numbers `32, 6, 23, 8, 69, 80, 48, 36` represent? How do they relate to a `DateTime`?

Comment: Here is the rub, those bytes dont relate to ticks / a long version of a DateTime, you are missing vital informaiton

Comment: @Dai - `.Reverse()` doesn't seem to help.

Comment: I doubt its unix time, its not in hex, its not ticks, changing endian doesn't help, i give up

Comment: When the bytes are interpreted as big-endian unsigned 64-bit integers, the difference between them is `476784` - and this is meant to represent a time-difference of about `9h, 0m, 7s`.

Comment: *"Then I need convert this string to a byte array..."* You have given us a byte array, so you have already done this step. Maybe something went wrong there? Can you give us the original string (for example, as a list of unicode code points)?

Comment: Working answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62576969/766304